# If $\arcsin(x^2+y^2)+\arctan(4y^2-1)+\operatorname{arcsec}(x)=a$ then $a$ belongs to

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse-function

> If $\arcsin(x^2+y^2)+\arctan(4y^2-1)+\operatorname{arcsec}(x)=a$ then $a$ belongs to

p) $\{0\}$

q) $(\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2)$

r) $[0,\frac\pi2)$

s) $\mathrm R$

t) $\mathrm R-\{0\}$

**My Attempt:**

$\operatorname{arcsec}(x)$ is defined when $x^2\ge1$, therefore for $\arcsin(x^2+y^2)$ to define, $y^2=0, x^2=1$, so,

$$a=\frac\pi2-\frac\pi4+0=\frac\pi4;\;x=1$$

Or, $$a=\frac\pi2-\frac\pi4+\pi=\frac{5\pi}4;\;x=-1$$

Therefore, my answer is $a\in\{\frac\pi4,\frac{5\pi}4\}$

But the answer given is p), q), r), s).

Can you share your thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Your work looks good to me. Are you sure you've copied down the problem correctly?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut thanks, yes, I have copied the problem correctly. The book has some typos here and there. So, maybe this is one such question.